# X and Y are i.r.v with uniform density on {0, 1, ... N}. Find densities of min(X, Y), max(X, Y), |Y - X|

Tags: probability

X and Y are i.r.v with uniform density on {0, 1, ... N}. Find densities of min(X, Y), max(X, Y), |Y - X|

I've been trying to solve these problems and the best I could have came up is solving the first two over a small subset of values 1, 2, 3, 4 and then recognizing a pattern. But I was wondering what is a general way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Z:=\min(X,Y)$. Then the event $(Z=n)$ is equal to $(X=n,\,Y\ge n)\cup^*(X>n,\,Y=n)$ where $\cup^*$ denotes *disjoint union*, so we have
$$P(Z=n)=\frac 1{N+1}\cdot \frac{N-n+1}{N+1}\ +\ \frac{N-n}{N+1}\cdot\frac 1{N+1}\ =\frac{2N-2n+1}{(N+1)^2}\,.$$
The case of $\max(X,Y)$ can be derived similarly.

For the third one, if now $Z=|Y-X|$, then $(Z=0)\ =\ (X=Y)$ with $P(Z=0)=\frac1{N+1}$ and $(Z=n)\ =\ \bigcup_k^*(X=k,\,Y=k+n)\ \cup^*\ \bigcup_k^*(X=k+n,\,Y=k)$ if $n>0$.
Count the number of $k$'s such that $P(X=k,\,Y=k+n)\ne 0$ then you're basically done.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that what I needed!